# jQuery select menu ajax 3 levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 3 select fields that should be connected to each other.

The code is working, except the second select, which shows the correct chosen value but at console log gives the first option value even though show at the page that the second value is still selected.

Here is my jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#country').change(function(){
        var countryid = $(this).val();
        $.post('selectcity.php', {'countryid' : countryid}, function(data){
            if(data==0) {
                $('#city').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
            } else {
                $('#city').parent().find('.select_container').html(data);
                var city_id = $('#city').find(":selected").val();
                console.log(city_id);
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

HTML

```
<select id="country" class="select_container">
 <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<select id="city" class="select_container"></select>
<select id="item_id"  class="select_container " ></select>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Show HTML also. Better still, post a jsFiddle. We need to be able to duplicate your error. Make it easy for us to help.

Comment: HTML posted thanks @philtune

Comment: Try using .on("change") instead of .change() http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: not working for me case it will work with user change at the select menu, but i need it to work on page load or user change

Answer (score 0):

the jQuery code is correct , sorry to bother everyone they problem was because at the php file the value for each item were the same had to adjust that and it works as i wanted to be

this is the old (wrong)php code

```
    <?php 

if (isset($_REQUEST['countryid']) && $_REQUEST['countryid']!="") {
    $citynewval = $_REQUEST['countryid'] + 3;
    $citynewval2 = $_REQUEST['countryid'] + 5;
    $citynewval3 = $_REQUEST['countryid'] + 8;

    echo'<option value="'.$citynewval.'"';
    if (!(strcmp($citynewval, 6))) {echo ' selected';}
    echo '>'.$citynewval.'</option>';

    echo'<option value="'.$citynewval.'"';
    if (!(strcmp($citynewval2, 6))) {echo ' selected';}
    echo '>'.$citynewval2.'</option>';

    echo'<option value="'.$citynewval.'"';
    if (!(strcmp($citynewval3, 6))) {echo ' selected';}
    echo '>'.$citynewval3.'</option>';

    }else {
        echo 0;
        }?>
```

and this is the code after corrections

```
    <?php 

if (isset($_REQUEST['countryid']) && $_REQUEST['countryid']!="") {
    $citynewval = $_REQUEST['countryid'] + 3;
    $citynewval2 = $_REQUEST['countryid'] + 5;
    $citynewval3 = $_REQUEST['countryid'] + 8;

    echo'<option value="'.$citynewval.'"';
    if (!(strcmp($citynewval, 6))) {echo ' selected';}
    echo '>'.$citynewval.'</option>';

    echo'<option value="'.$citynewval2.'"';
    if (!(strcmp($citynewval2, 6))) {echo ' selected';}
    echo '>'.$citynewval2.'</option>';

    echo'<option value="'.$citynewval3.'"';
    if (!(strcmp($citynewval3, 6))) {echo ' selected';}
    echo '>'.$citynewval3.'</option>';

    }else {
        echo 0;
        }?>
```

thanks for those who were trying to help